# Evaluating string as expression

Tags: angularjs

Can't seem to find any examples of this in AngularJS (only other languages).

basically I have extracted the attribute of an element, but it returns as a string `"row.item.nestedSettings"`. I want to do something like `$scope.updateSettings(row.item.nestedSettings)` instead of `$scope.updateSettings("row.item.nestedSettings")`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you post your updateSettings function code please. Also if you don't want a string then why pass a string as a parameter? If your parameter is a string and you need it to be something else why don't you type cast it? I am assuming this attribute is a number? type cast it as an int in the function using "parseInt()".

Comment: is this element a directive ? do you use '@' instead of '=' to "inject the attribute" in your scope's directive ?

Answer (score 0):

with angular you should also have the full javascript functionality.

angular documentation describes the use of scope.$eval as can be seen below. It should be possible to use the saem in your situation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

```
var scope = ng.$rootScope.Scope();
scope.a = 1;
scope.b = 2;

expect(scope.$eval('a+b')).toEqual(3);
```

Comment: most likely `$scope.$eval` if it is the case.

Comment: You are right. Checked the angular documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

`var scope = ng.$rootScope.Scope();
scope.a = 1;
scope.b = 2;

expect(scope.$eval('a+b')).toEqual(3);
expect(scope.$eval(function(scope){ return scope.a + scope.b; })).toEqual(3);`